# AWS Unknown service textract issue

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, ocr, boto3

AWS has instroduced Textract API recently and while playing around encounterd an issue like

> botocore.exceptions.UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'textract'

I have followed [this AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/analyzing-document-text.html) and used Python boto3.

Comment: What region are you trying to use it in? This service is only available in **us-east-1**, **us-east-2**, **us-west-2**, **eu-west-1**

Comment: @AlexK using us-east-2 region

Answer (score 1):

It's still in preview, you have to sign up for the preview

Comment: How do we do it?

Answer (score 0):

Textract has launched recently on November 28, 2018 in this re:Invent. I think the version of your local Python does not support this service in boto library. you should upgrade your python.

Answer (score 0):

That error is generated when your version of boto3 is not updated to the version that supports the Textract API.

You need to update boto3 to the latest version. In my case, I running this command addressed the issue:
 `pip install boto3==1.9.108`

Also make sure you have the latest available version of awscli:

`aws --version`